# Switch between native view and hybrid webview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, hybrid-mobile-app

I have 3 files "AppDelegate.m", "MainViewController.m" and "ViewController.m"

In "AppDelegate.m" file, I have this function:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];     //line1
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];     //line2
    //return YES;      //line3
}
```

When I run the above function it shows the "hybrid view" but when I comment the line1, line2 and uncomment the line3 it shows the "native view".

How can I call the line3 "native view" on click of a button function which is created in a file abc.m in subfolder of the project and vice-versa.

NOTE: "MainViewController.m" file have hybrid view and "ViewController.m" have native view.

Comment: Just push the viewcontroller on button click. and set root viewcontroller as MainViewController.m in storyboard.

Comment: I already have a function which gets triggered on button click (present on hybrid view)


- (void)demofunc:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{

}
@end

The above function is present on subfolder of the project. So how can i push the viewcontroller and and set root viewcontroller as MainViewController.m in storyboard. I'm new in this so i don't know much. Thanks

Comment: Click on the yellow color icon on top of the viewController and follow below instructions.

Answer (score 1):

> Just tick is initial View Controller after selecting MainViewController

[image]

Or Use This Code

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:vc];
```

Comment: MainViewController does not have View Controller section so i cannot tick "Is initial View Controller"

Comment: what do you mean by "hybrid view"?

Comment: I'm working on Cordova app in which i have to switch between Cordova hybrid view and iOS Native view.
Cordova app launches successfully showing the Cordova hybrid view after calling the function mentioned in question.

Now, i have created a iOS Native view(storyboard) which is also works when i change the above function to:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
} 
Both these works one at a time. Now i want to show that native view(storybboard) on  - (void)demofunc called. How can i do this?

Comment: UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
    
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    
    UIViewController *viewController =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
    
    window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: I have used your code and just change the "Main" to my storyboard file name but the view still remains the same.
And i'm getting green arrow Thread 1:breakpoint 1.1 2.1 at start of your code.
Is there any thing else i've to change in your code to make it work?

Comment: I have used both the code but the above question is for commented code i.e.
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds]; UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController‌​"]; window.rootViewController = viewController; [window makeKeyAndVisible];